# How ellipsoid is defined with respect to some norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am just curious. A unit ball with respect to some norm $\|\|$ is just $\|x\|=1$ for $x\in\Bbb R^n$. Then how do we define an ellipsoid in $\Bbb R^n$ with respect to some norm $\|\|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$||x||=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i^2}$, for $a_i>0$

If you want to have an ellipsoid whose axes are not parallel to the axes of $\Bbb R^n$, you write the norm as $$||x||^2=xMx^T$$ where $M$ is positive definite